# How to slice a struct array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, slice

How can I extract a specific field from each element of a Matlab struct array?

```
>> clear x
>> x(1).a = 6;
>> x(2).a = 7;
```

I'd like an array containing 6 and 7. Neither `x(:).a` nor `x.a` do what I want.

```
>> x(:).a

ans =    

     6


ans =

     7
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No problem - just use :

```
arr = [x.a];
```

It will concat all of the values that you need.
If you have a more complex data, you can use the curly bracers:

```
b(1).x = 'John';
b(2).x = 'Doe';
arr = {b.x};
```

Answer (score 2):

For a multi-dimensional array, you need

```
reshape([x.a], size(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

If elements of the struct are strings, the accepted solution concatenates all cells.
The more general

```
vertcat(x.a)
```

works in all cases.
[Ref](http://%25%20See%20https://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/indexing-struct-td2067481.html)

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, I am almost sure that MATLAB has no nice way of doing what you want.  You will have to either use a for loop to construct a new array, or else go back and redesign your data structures.  For example you might be able to use a struct-of-arrays rather than an array-of-structs.